# JDK 7 with Android SDK R13 in windows 7

Tags: android, eclipse, java-7

I want to use JDK 7 64bit for android development. But in system requirement of android development it is said that it need's "JDK 5 or JDK 6". Is there any problem if i want to use latest JDK 64bit with latest android SDK and new eclipse IDE 64bit?

Note:

Comment: It says so because JDK 7 wasn't released when they wrote that, but I still don't see a point in using JDK 7 for Android development since the phones doesn't support that version.

Comment: JDK 7 was literally released yesterday.

Comment: I don't find an SDK r13. I only see an SDK r12 (July 2011) on http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: It's been a little over three years after this question was asked, and the document (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) for the Eclipse plugin references JDK 6. The link provided takes you to an Oracle page which displays obvious links for downloading Java SE 8 and 7 products. If you're clever, you can navigate to JDK 6 downloads with a couple clicks from that page. I think "Use Android Studio" is being slyly written between the lines :)

Answer (score 4):

JDK 7 64-bit works without issue on Windows7 64-bit, however you will probably need to download both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the SDK. I'm not sure why they haven't solved this issue but the fix works, and JDK 7 works fine with Android.

Answer (score 3):

The JDK detection problem in the Android SDK is a known (and annoying) issue.

To solve this, after getting the message that the SDK wasn't detected, just hit the "Back" button and then the "Next" button again and it should detect the JDK properly

Answer (score 2):

Some systems I installed it on worked with the 64-bit JDK, and some didn't detect it, requiring me to install the 32-bit one as well. Either way, it worked with Eclipse x64 just fine.