# IDEA: Android cannot work with Java 7

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

when I create a Android project. IDEA has noticed error that this version is not support JDK 1.7. Does It true, or there are some problems with my machine.
If it true, so I must install JDK 1.6 or older, right ?

I'm using latest version of IDEA (11 Ultimate).

thanks :)

Comment: see this link, it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873395/jdk-7-with-android-sdk-r13-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long time I get a headache with this. After I downgrade to JDK ver 6, It works fine.
If you want to use JDK 7 (because It must, you should use Eclipse. It work well for me too :) )

Answer (score 1):

Using JDK 1.6 is recommended for Android development, so just install Java 6. Next IDEA update will allow to use JDK 1.7.