# Switch statement with string as argument in Android

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I would like to use a switch statement as in Java 1.7 which also allows `switch(someString)`. However if I change the java compiler to 1.7 the project breaks and I either have to go back to 1.5 or use `android tools-> fix project`.

Is there any way to use switch with Strings in android development?

Comment: @Deepak It is in Java7, thus the reason for this question.

Comment: The answer provided in this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java) shows you how to somewhat work around the switch with string restriction before java 7. If you do not want this approach, you're stuck with if/elses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367629/android-coding-with-switch-string/32225734#32225734

Answer (score 5):

EDIT

Personally, I have not tried, but according to the  [Android System Requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) page, it is unsupported.  That said, it does not mean that it wouldn't work, just that you are unlikely to receive much/any help on the subject from Google/Android.

> JDK 5 or JDK 6 (JRE alone is not sufficient)

On a potentially positive note, (found with the help of @Emil H and his comment) I have found these bit of information online:

From [Dalvik on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29):

> Programs are commonly written in a dialect of Java and compiled to bytecode. Then they are converted from Java Virtual Machine-compatible .class files to Dalvik-compatible .dex (Dalvik Executable) files...

If the bytecode doesn't change from version 6 to 7 (excluding the added `invokedynamic` mentioned by @David Schwartz, which `switch` statements should not be using.), then it should work...

Comment: Are you sure about this. I thought that the dex compiler worked with the byte code. And as far as I know there is java 7 does not add anything new at the byte code level... I could be wrong thou...

Comment: @EmilH Java 7 adds at least `invokedynamic` to the Java byte code per [JSR292](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=292).

Comment: @David Scwartz Yeah, but Java doesn't use that right? It is mainly to increase support for dynamic languages on the jvm like Jython etc?

Comment: Excellent points.  I have updated my answer to reflect this information.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use JDK7 with android. Check this answer to a related question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7481063/355499

**EDIT:**

Tried it out locally and everything works fine with JDK7 (it's what I use when developing). However, I can't find a way to change the compliance level from 1.6 to 1.7 in my android project. If you really want to do this I guess you would have to resort to building your project by some other means than using Eclipse. For instance using an ant script or similar. Might be a bit more work than it is worth though.

Answer (score 0):

For now it is no possible:
although in Java 1.7 compiler it was introduced the **switch** statement with String, unfortunately Android requires version 1.6 or 1.5.
So we have to wait.