# Android coding with switch (String)

Tags: java, android, string, switch-statement

I'm developing an android app on eclipse, when I try some code like

```
switch(String){
 ......
}
```

it give me the following error

```
Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted
```

so I changed the compiler to 1.7, then it give me another error

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

So, is there anyway to let switch(String) works in android application?
or I have no choice but to use

```
if(){}
else if(){}
else if(){}
........
```

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java  It's got some interesting answers

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`switch` statement on `String` objects is a new feature introduced in Java 1.7. Unfortunatelly Android requires version 1.6 or 1.5. This is why you have to forget for some time about such constructions.

You can avoid using if-statements-chain by storing the map of methods which will be executed for certain `String`: `Map<String, Method>`. You can always encapsulate `Method` it with some `Handler` object. Look here for more info: [How to remove large if-else-if chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349883/how-to-remove-large-if-else-if-chain)

and

[why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913495/refactoring-if-else-logic/2913518#2913518)

Comment: This answer is deprecated with release of KitKat. Check [latest answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367629/android-coding-with-switch-string/19722741#19722741)

Answer (score 94):

With the Release of API 19 KitKat you can now do this !!!! This is the change you need for android studio for existing projects. ensure that you are using JDK 1.7 or later and Gradle plugin 0.6.1 or later

> ```
> android {
> compileSdkVersion 19
> buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
>
> defaultConfig {
>     minSdkVersion 7
>     targetSdkVersion 19
> }
>
> compileOptions {
>     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
>     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
> } }
> ```

Comment: @Eddwhis yes, it will still work!
Source: Tested `switch ("test") { case "test": Log.e("Yay", "It Works"); break; }` on API 18!

Comment: So is it the `compileOptions` which are the key thing here?

Comment: @bclymer You're partially right. It truly does work below API level 19, because it's about compiler behavior and not about device behavior. However, Your test proves nothing, because of Java optimalization. Compiler may try to reduce memory usage by reusing String objects in literals - so your test **may or may not** pass even before Java 1.7.

Answer (score 6):

You have no choice. You can't work `Switch` with Strings (at least for  now). Following message explicitly conforms that.

> Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the latest android build tools. Android started supporting Java 7 feature since API 19.

The best part is that it will work even if you set your minSdkVersion lower than 19. Quoting this [android developer page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7):

> Note that you can use minSdkVersion with a value earlier than 19, for all language features except try with resources. If you want to use try with resources, you will need to also use a minSdkVersion of 19.

Answer (score 3):

Here is other alternative for android with java 5 or 6

```
public enum Command  {text, image, other};

String enumTest = "text";
try{
    Command command  = Command.valueOf(enumTest);
}
catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("Tag", "Command not found: " + enumTest);
}
switch (command){
   case image:
      break;
   case  text:
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I assume most people are using Android Studio with at least a minimum of Java 7, then the answer now is, **Yes, you can switch Strings in Android**, even for minSdkVersion versions < 19. Here is an example of how to do it, taken from the [Java SE Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html):

```
public String getTypeOfDayWithSwitchStatement(String dayOfWeekArg) {
     String typeOfDay;
     switch (dayOfWeekArg) {
         case "Monday":
             typeOfDay = "Start of work week";
             break;
         case "Tuesday":
         case "Wednesday":
         case "Thursday":
             typeOfDay = "Midweek";
             break;
         case "Friday":
             typeOfDay = "End of work week";
             break;
         case "Saturday":
         case "Sunday":
             typeOfDay = "Weekend";
             break;
         default:
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day of the week: " + dayOfWeekArg);
     }
     return typeOfDay;
}
```

The docs also note:

- Using string switching is generally faster than chained `if`-`else`.
- It is as if each case were using `String.equals`.