# Is it possible to use already String in Switch?

Tags: java, android, string, switch-statement

I heard that the new version of Java String made ​​support in the operator Switch. Does it work now in Android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367629/android-coding-with-switch-string

Comment: wasn't try yourself faster?

Comment: you could resort to enums and their `valueOf(String)` to be used with switches

Comment: @kiruwka That will only work for if your set of strings is limited.

Comment: @m0skit0 Definitely. But that is usually the case when you want to use switch, right ?

Comment: @kiruwka Not necessarily, you might want to check several values and if it's not any of them do a default.

Answer (score 2):

No. `switch/case` for `String` is only available for Java 7+, and Android Dalvik is based on Java 6.

**EDIT**: note that starting with API 16 there are some Java 7 features included, check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153989/java-7-language-features-with-android).

Comment: From the "other answer", it looks to me that some of those Java 7 features depend only on having a compiler that understands them, and is independent of what Android version is running on the device; and that `switch(String)` is one of those.  Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @ajb Might be, I really don't know, that's why I'm referring to the other answer. Personally I've always used Java 6.