# Screen orientation settings in android app

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I would like to create orientation setting in my application ("`Portrait`", "`Landscape`", "`Auto`").

I created this option in my settings activity, but i don't know how to set this orientation settings to my application (or activity) programatically at runtime.

In my activity in `onCreate()` I tried:

```
    sharedPrefSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    switch (sharedPrefSettings.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, "0")) {
        case "0":
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);

            break;
        case "1":
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            break;
        case "2":
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

            break;
    }
```

but it bad working:

Activity is not rotate immediately when settings are changed (i must recreate activity to apply changes)

When app is first opened, activity is in default (system) orientation, and after about second it recreates with orientation from my settings.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Check this Out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726657/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-android

Comment: Xaver Kapeller, i updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)) of `setRequestedOrientation`:

> **public void setRequestedOrientation (int requestedOrientation)**
>
> Change the desired orientation of this activity.
>   If the activity is currently in the foreground or otherwise impacting
>   the screen orientation, the screen will immediately be changed
>   (possibly causing the activity to be restarted). Otherwise, this will
>   be used the next time the activity is visible.

So it should work as you describe, I just tested it and I don't run into any problems or errors. The error must be somewhere else.

---

The error could also be here:

```
switch (sharedPrefSettings.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, "0")) {
    case "0":
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);

        break;
    case "1":
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        break;
    case "2":
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        break;
}
```

You are using switch on a `String`. Until recently that was not supported in Android. Either you have to be sure that your language level is set to 1.7 or you can use `Integers` or if statements instead:

```
switch (sharedPrefSettings.getInt(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, -1)) {

    case 1:
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        break;

    case 2:
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        break;

    default:
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
        break;
}
```

Also you can use `default` like I just did to create a safer and more general logic.

---

The error could also possibly be here:

```
sharedPrefSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

`getDefaultSharedPreferences()` is potentially dangerous and you should avoid using this instead create your `SharedPreferences` explicitly like this:

```
sharedPrefSettings = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

---

So in the end when all mistakes are fixed your code should look like this:

```
sharedPrefSettings = getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE);

switch (sharedPrefSettings.getInt(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, -1)) {

    case 1:
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        break;

    case 2:
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        break;

    default:
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367629/android-coding-with-switch-string/19722741#19722741

Comment: i use language level 1.7, so i can use switch with String.