# How can I write this Java logic code more efficiently?

Tags: java, android, logic, boolean-logic

I have four TextViews in my activity. Based on an incoming message, I want to change the format of these four TextViews so that one is larger and bold while the rest are smaller and regularly styled. To do this, I create two methods, setTextNormal and setTextBig. In order to change the numbers I am using this bit of code:

```
                if (tokens[2].equals("0")) {
                    setTextBig(text1);
                    setTextNormal(text2);
                    setTextNormal(text3);
                    setTextNormal(text4);
                }
                if (tokens[2].equals("1")) {
                    setTextBig(text2);
                    setTextNormal(text1);
                    setTextNormal(text3);
                    setTextNormal(text4);
                }
                if (tokens[2].equals("2")) {
                    setTextBig(text3);
                    setTextNormal(text2);
                    setTextNormal(text1);
                    setTextNormal(text4);
                }
                if (tokens[2].equals("3")) {
                    setTextBig(text4);
                    setTextNormal(text2);
                    setTextNormal(text3);
                    setTextNormal(text1);
                }
```

Notice that for each if statement, one of the TextViews are being set to big and the rest to normal. It works, but is there a more efficient way for me to set these TextViews?

Comment: You could setTextNormal all views before the ifs then setTextBig the view you want in the if block.

Comment: @AreM Please work harder to make the title of your Question specific and meaningful. You can use the Edit link/button to change it.

Comment: If your two methods are already written, I would recommend using my solution. If they have not yet been written, I would go with the solution @Andreas proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest changing your code to have a `setTextSize(text, boolean big)` method, and use it as follows:

```
String token = tokens[2];
setTextSize(text1, /*big*/token.equals("0"));
setTextSize(text2, /*big*/token.equals("1"));
setTextSize(text3, /*big*/token.equals("2"));
setTextSize(text4, /*big*/token.equals("3"));
```

Comment: I wonder why I got a down-vote. The question stated that `setTextNormal` and `setTextBig` was created by OP, so going with a different implementation is a very valid answer. --- But just in case it's because someone don't like that you have to look at the signature of `setTextSize` to see what parameter 2 means, I'll add comments to help any reader of the code. That's a good pattern anyway, especially for boolean parameters.

Comment: Very clean and elegant. Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

Make an array of your text variables like `[text1, text2, text3, text4]`

Set all texts normal at the start, as other users have suggested, and then do:
`setTextBig(texts[tokens[2]]);`

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure if more efficent by much really but just setting all text to normal first and then only changing the specific text to large works such as.

```
setTextNormal(text4);
setTextNormal(text2);
setTextNormal(text3);
setTextNormal(text1);
if (tokens[2].equals("0")) {
    setTextBig(text1);
} else if (tokens[2].equals("1")) {
    setTextBig(text2);
} else if (tokens[2].equals("2")) {
    setTextBig(text3);
} else if (tokens[2].equals("3")) {
    setTextBig(text4);
}
```

Comment: You loose a } on the first if. Correct also indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can do something like that.

```
 setTextNormal(text1);
 setTextNormal(text2);
 setTextNormal(text3);
 setTextNormal(text4);

 if (tokens[2].equals("0")) {
     setTextBig(text1);
 } else if (tokens[2].equals("1")) {
     setTextBig(text2);
 } else if (tokens[2].equals("2")) {
     setTextBig(text3);
 } else if (tokens[2].equals("3")) {
     setTextBig(text4);
 }
```

Check if it is possible to set a text as normal and after set it as big.

Answer (score 0):

```
void setNormal(){
    setTextNormal(text1);
    setTextNormal(text2);
    setTextNormal(text3);
    setTextNormal(text4);
}

switch(tokens[2]){
    case "0":
        setNormal();
        setTextBig(text1);
        break;
    case "1":
        setNormal();
        setTextBig(text2);
        break;
    case "2":
        setNormal();
        setTextBig(text3);
        break;
    case "3":
        setNormal();
        setTextBig(text4);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: This is a logical alternative, but is almost as lengthy as the original solution.

Comment: I think switch case is more faster than if else :)

Comment: You can't switch on a String.

Comment: Man, of course you can. this code is working, check this out @323go

 public static void main(String[] args){
  String a = "1";
  switch(a){
   case "1":
   System.out.println("abc");
  }
 }

Comment: @323go you can definitely switch on a String, I use it all the time. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19722741/1499541

Comment: Regardless, this isn't even switching on a string. `tokens[2]` is an int it appears.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the repeated similarity into a method

setText(String large, String ... small)

// note 2nd arg is vararg which is one or more arguments

//setTextLarge(large)

//Iterate over small which is a vararg array and setTextSmall

Then to use the extracted method

If token is 0 setText(text1, text2, text3)

If token is 2 setText(text2, text1, text3)

If token is 2 setText(text3, text1, text2)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (tokens[2].equals("0")) {
            setTextsOrder(text1, text2, text3, text4);
        } else if (tokens[2].equals("1")) {
            setTextsOrder(text2, text1, text3, text4);
        } else if (tokens[2].equals("2")) {
            setTextsOrder(text3, text2, text1, text4);
        } else if (tokens[2].equals("3")) {
            setTextsOrder(text4, text2, text3, text1);
        }
    }
    . 
    .

    private static void setTextsOrder(String text, String... texts) {
        setTextBig(text);
        for (String textIt : texts) {
            setTextNormal(textIt);
        }
    }
```