# Adding IF statement into each array index value in MulitSelectList preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preference, android-multiselectlistpreference

I'm trying to put an IF statement for each array index value, the value is from MultiSelectList preference. but I'm having problem on doing it, here is my code please help me.

```
public void displaySelectedDoa(View view) {

mySharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Set<String> selectionsDoa = mySharedPreferences.getStringSet("selectedDoaKey", null);
String[] selectedDoa = selectionsDoa.toArray(new String[]{});

if (selectedDoa == "0") { // if index number = 0
    //do something at here
}
if (selectedDoa == "1") { // if index nuber = 1
    //do here
}
```

}

this is my MultiSelectList from preference fragment

```
<MultiSelectListPreference
    android:title="Select Doa"
    android:summary="select your doa"
    android:key="selectedDoaKey"
    android:entries="@array/select_doa"
    android:entryValues="@array/select_doa_value"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
CharSequence[] selectedDoa = selectionsDoa.toArray(new String[]{});
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedDoa.length; i++){
        String index = selectedDoa[i].toString();
    }

 if (index.equals("string")){
//do here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

selectedDoa is an array not a single string value so you will need to check all the selected indices 
try this

```
for (int i=0;i<selectedDoa.length;i++){
        String index=selectedDoa[i];
        switch (index){
            case "0":
                //do what zero does
                continue;
            case "1":
                //do what one does
                continue;
        }
    }
```

as our friend Vaiden said if switch string are an issue

replace them with

```
if(index.equals("0"){
//do what zero does
}
else if(index.equals("1"){
//do what one does
}
```

Comment: Switch blocks with Strings are only supported on API >= 19 (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19722741/606351). For older Androids either parse the String to an int, or use cascaded IF statements with .equals()

Comment: on the String index = selectedDoa[ I ]; 

there is an error saying incompatible type . Required:java.lang.String   Found:Java.lang.CharSequence . how to repair this ?

Comment: hi it is selectedDoa[i]; also the code is compiling fine i tested it on android studio 
mySharedPreferences.getStringSet("selectedDoaKey", null);
        String[] selectedDoa = selectionsDoa.toArray(new String[]{});
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedDoa.length; i++) {
            String index = selectedDoa[i];
            if (index.equals("0")) {

            } else if (index.equals("1")) {
                
            }
        }